# How to post data from all pages at the same time in codeigniter pagination

Tags: codeigniter

I am submitting user status through form on first page it is working fine. But if I try to send data from page 1 and 2 at the same time I am not able to do that. Any suggestion how I can save status value when I go to next page and submit both page's values at the same time.

[image]

Comment: is your pagination number `2` is a link or just a javascript hide and show function?

Comment: 2 is next page link, it also contain record like page 1

Comment: Use a query string, and use the pagination config to apply it to your links.

Comment: @BrianGottier can you please give some explanation because i am new to codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

### Query strings attached to CodeIgniter pagination

So, you like to create a paginated search feature, or add some value to persist in your pagination, and CodeIgniter makes that easy.

If you take a look at the Pagination Class, https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html, you will see the configuration option "reuse_query_string", and you want to set that to TRUE when configuring your pagination:

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

In your case, you said that you are submitting a user status. You haven't shown code that specifies how you are submitting, but based on your picture I'm assuming you're using the POST HTTP method. When paginating, it's better if you use the GET HTTP method if possible. The difference is in your form's open tag:

```
<!-- Get method uses a query string -->
<form method="get">
    ... Get is good for pagination ...
</form>

<!-- Post method does not use a query string -->
<form method="post">
    ... Not as good as get for pagination ...
</form>
```

If you use a query string, and if you set the reuse_query_string configuration option to TRUE, there's nothing else to do, because the query string will persist in your pagination links. That means that in your model, you simply look for the status like this:

```
$status = $this->input->get('status');
```

You obviously need that for the query that counts database results, as well as the query that fetches the data.

The last thing to think about would be how to stop pagination of the selected status. I'll usually have a reset button that is more or less a simple link, but it doesn't include the query string, so there is no more status in your case.

That's really all there is to it.